# email address confirmation with flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a web application with Flask.
I created the code is working, but the way I did it, it is possible to access in url.

`auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, template_folder=TEMPLATES)`

```py
@auth.route('/singup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def singup():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate():
        user = User(
            name=form.name.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=form.password.data,
            confirmed=False
        )
        create_user(user)

        token = generate_confirmation_token(user.email)
        confirm_url = url_for('auth.confirm_email', token=token, _external=True)
        html = render_template('auth/email_msg.html', confirm_url=confirm_url, name=user.name)
        subject = "Confirme seu e-mail"
        send_email(
            to=user.email,
            subject=subject,
            template=html)

        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for("auth.verify_email"))

    return render_template('auth/singup.html', form=form)


@auth.route('/confirm/<token>')
@login_required
def confirm_email(token):
    try:
        email = confirm_token(token)
    except:
        flash('O link de confirmação não é válido ou expirou.', 'danger')
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first_or_404()
    if user.confirmed:
        flash('Conta confirmada com sucesso.', 'success')
    else:
        user.confirmed = True
        user.confirmed_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        create_user(user)

    return redirect(url_for('auth.verify_email'))


@auth.route('/confirm')
@login_required
def verify_email():
    return render_template('auth/confirm_email.html')
```

Like I said, it's working. My question is whether it is possible to block access via the url "http://127.0.0.1:5000/confirm"

I tried this, but all routes became variables:

```py
@auth.route('/<token>')
@login_required
def confirm_email(token):
   ...
```